# Creating a new AVD

Tags: android, android-studio

Any idea why the OK button is deactive?

[image]

even with skin, ok button is still deactive!
[image]

Comment: You didnt select skin

Comment: hmm it doesn't say like a red error or warning that it is obligatory! I think the UI should enhance then! btw with even selecting a skin it is still deactive!

Comment: just choose `skin`

Comment: Choose Skin as default and make sure to install System image for emulator to work and also mark Use Host GPU so that you emulator will run faster

Comment: hey please look at my comment! Selecting the skin wouldn't help! I also updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have `No system images installed for this target` (as it says in the screenshot).
You should open the SDK manager and install the appropriate system images.

Answer (score 0):

Choose Skin as default and make sure to install System image for emulator to work and also mark Use Host GPU so that you emulator will run faster